# unit test angular bootstrap modal service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, unit-testing, jasmine

I have created a common `ModalService` and this is used for two diferrnt type of dialogs. `CancelDialog` and `ErrorDialog` will be popped up as per parameter passed to service.

***Why do we Unit Test when functionality is working fine??***

i.e This will show an `ErrorDialog`

```
ModalService.openModal('Analysis Error', 'I am Error Type', 'Error');
```

All is working fine but am stuck with Unit Test. Here is working [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/3YdnkT4vPASzdYf44btX).
Please help in covering Unit Test for this.

How to do Unit Test for `openErrorModal` & `openCancelModal` in below service.

**ModalService**

```
// common modal service
validationApp.service('ModalService',
  function($uibModal) {

    return {
      openModal: openModal
    };

    function openErrorModal(title, message, callback) {
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'ErrorDialog.html',
        controller: 'ErrorDialogCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'md',
        resolve: {
          message: function() {
            return message;
          },
          title: function() {
            return title;
          },
          callback: function() {
            return callback;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function openCancelModal(title, message, callback) {
      $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'CancelDialog.html',
        controller: 'ErrorDialogCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        backdrop: 'static',
        size: 'md',
        resolve: {
          message: function() {
            return message;
          },
          title: function() {
            return title;
          },
          callback: function() {
            return callback;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function openModal(title, message, modalType, callback) {
      if (modalType === "Error") {
        openErrorModal(title, message, callback);
      } else {
        openCancelModal(title, message, callback);
      }
    }
  }
);
```

How to Unit Test `onOk` , `onContinue` & `onDiscard` in below controller.

**DialogController**

```
//controller fot dialog
validationApp.controller('ErrorDialogCtrl',
  function($uibModalInstance, message, title, callback) {
    alert('from controller');
    var vm = this;
    vm.message = message;
    vm.onOk = onOk;
    vm.onContinue = onContinue;
    vm.onDiscard = onDiscard;
    vm.callback = callback;
    vm.title = title;

    function onOk() {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    function onContinue() {
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }

    function onDiscard() {
      vm.callback();
      $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
  });
```

Comment: what exactly is your question regarding unit testing this dialog?

Comment: I am quite new with Angular & Unit Testing.  I have done UT for simple controller. But doing UT for this service and controller is going over my head. Not sure what to do, I tried :(.

Comment: what framework do you use?

Comment: jasmine and angular 1.5

Comment: ok, let me provide some pseudocode to get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separately test service and controllers. For controllers, you need to test that methods of `uibModalInstance` are called when controller methods are called. You don't actually need to test that dialog closes, when `close` method is called. That is the task of those who implemented uibModal.

So here is the test for controller:

```
describe('ErrorDialogCtrl', function() {

    // inject the module of your controller
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('tests that close method is called on modal dialog', function() {
        var $uibModalInstance = {
            close: jasmine.createSpy('close')
        };

        var callback = function() {};
        var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $uibModalInstance: $uibModalInstance, message: {}, callback: callback });

        controller.onOk();
        expect($uibModalInstance.close).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Here is the simply test for service:

```
describe('ModalService', function () {

    var $injector;
    var $uibModal;

    // inject the module of your controller
    beforeEach(module('app', function($provide) {
        $uibModal = {
            open: jasmine.createSpy('open')
        };

        $provide.value('$uibModal', $uibModal);
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$injector_) {
        $injector = _$injector_;
    }));

    it('tests that openErrorModal is called', function () {
        var modalService = $injector.get('ModalService');
        modalService.openModal(null, null, "Error");

        expect($uibModal.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
            controller: "ErrorDialogCtrl"
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: I followed up but end up getting this error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: messageProvider <- message`

Comment: yeah, it's because your controller requires them. I've udpated the answer

Comment: Thanks that worked, but one thing if I don't cover unit test  for **ModalService** my Pull Request won't get approval. Any heads up on that plzz.

Comment: @ankitd, updated. If you find this answer helpful upvote it and accept it if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: okay, it really helped. Upvoted :) controller part is working perfect. But service part throwing this error `Expected undefined to be 'Error'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125753/discussion-between-ankitd-and-maximus).